# Show image via javascript after page load

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to create an image which is initially hidden - but reveals itself once the document has loaded completely via the JavaScript file.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById("theImage").style.visibility = "visible";
});
```

```css
#theImage {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Kami Nelson Bio </title>
<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="KNelson-Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="KNelson_reveal.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="theImage">
        <img src="images/Kami-100.jpg" alt="Kami Nelson Image"/>
        </div>
      
      <div id="div1" class="fluid">
        <h1>Bio for Kami Nelson</h1>
        <p>Text</p>
        </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is this not working?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$(document).ready` is jQuery, and you're not using jQuery !

Comment: are you even sure the image shows when it's not hidden at all?

Comment: Probably does not matters but note that (currently your image might be cached by the browser, but) if you hard-refresh your DOM might be loaded, but your image might be still loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are missing the jQuery library reference
- You are not properly
  using selecter to select image of id `theImage`.
- `theImage` is supposed to be for the `img` tag.

**JavaScript**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#theImage").css('display':'block');
});
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
#theImage {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img id= "theImage" src="images/Kami-100.jpg" alt="Kami Nelson Image"/>
```

Comment: When I try to add the JS it says there is a syntax error on line 2, I added jquery script

Comment: did you do $("#theImage") instead of what you have?

Comment: Yes I copied yours exactly

Comment: hey, make the id of image to be theImage instead of div's .

Comment: Ok got it it was the brackets missing in .css ({'display':'block'});

Thank you!

Comment: What if I wanted a 5 second delay after the page load before the image loaded?

Comment: it would be : 

$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
    $("#theImage").css({'display':'block', 'border':'1px solid red'});        
    }, 5000);
});

http://jsfiddle.net/utrgnu8n/

Answer (score 2):

You should either include jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or use native `window.onload()` instead of `$(document).ready()`

```
window.onload=function () {
    document.getElementById("theImage").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just draw the image when the window loads?
give your image an id i'll use "image" for this example.

```
<script>
window.onload = function () 
{
$('#image').css({"display":"block";});
}
</script>
```

Comment: So, remove `$(document).ready` because the OP isn't using jQuery, then change the code inside to jQuery. Makes sense ?

Comment: Yeah that does make sense. My apologies, mixed up between native and jquery for a second then.

Comment: But then the answer makes no sense, why would you use `window.onload` instead of `$(document).ready` if you already had jQuery

Comment: edited, apologies. use native and then go back into jquery yes.

Comment: No need to apologize, I'm just asking why you're doing what you're doing?

Comment: document.ready loads when your html document is loaded, for what you want? the image to load after everything has loaded, system upload will wait until all other components are loaded before loading your image. (slightly after document load)